Why C-D bond is stronger than C-H bond though D is more heavier than H?
I read that as the atomic mass increases, the bond length increases and hence the bond strength decreases. Then why C-D bond is stronger than C-H bond?

Due to the anharmonicity of the C‐H/D vibrational potential energy function and
the lower ZPE of a C‐D bond, the average C‐D bond length is typically ~0.005 Å
shorter than an equivalent C‐H bond.  muni.cz - Bonding.pdf
